# How do i make these commands work as a script on android?

Tags: android, linux, shell

Basically i have this code and I want to have it run as a script whenever I run said script:

```
cp -r data/data/com.nintendo.zaba/files/assets/USEN/Message/* /storage/emulated/0/FireEmblem/Message 
cp -r data/data/com.nintendo.zaba/files/assets/USEN/UI/* /storage/emulated/0/FireEmblem/UI 
cp -r data/data/com.nintendo.zaba/files/assets/Common/UI/* /storage/emulated/0/FireEmblem/GoToCommon/UI 
cp -r data/data/com.nintendo.zaba/files/assets/Common/UI_Animation/* /storage/emulated/0/FireEmblem/GoToCommon/UI_Animation
```

I don't really know how to convert it so it runs as a .sh(?) file.

Comment: add `#!/bin/sh` as the first line, save, exit. Then `chmod +x myNintendoScript`. Run as `./myNintendoScript`. GOod luck.

Comment: I have root access on my phone as well as busybox and I added #!system/bin/sh as the first line. The chmod is just to add execute permissions to the script and I've tried that but alas to no effect.

Comment: I don't know much about scripting for android/busybox, but shouldn't it be `#!/system/bin/sh` ? note leading `/` char. I would still expect `#!/bin/sh` to work . Did you try it? Good luck.